# How to Customize chekout page and order details page liquid files

Tags: php, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I need to put customized product image in checkout page and order details page rather than original product image.
But I didn't find the liquid files in my store theme code.

How can I access these files or any alternative way of doing product image change in checkout and order detail page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some basic options available in the checkout via the General Settings customization ( font-family, colors and backgrounds ).

If you are looking for larger modifications ( html/css/js ) your only option is to buy a Shopify Plus account ( which is around $1000 per month ) and you will have access to the `checkout.liquid` file where you can modify the css/js and some of the html ( the form fields html structure can't be modified )

As for the single order page, the file is located in `customer/order.liquid`. You have full access to modify what ever you like in it.